# Quicksight pivot table sorting not working

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I made a pivot table with 4 dimensions in the Rows field well and 5 measures in the Values field well. I'm trying to sort the table according to one of the measures in the values field well but even when I set it to ascending order, the table is still sorted alphabetically according to one of the dimensions in rows field well. I did not apply any sorting to the dimensions.